# Combine regex capture groups into 1 array?

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I have the following regex to match words that are between [] or {} :

```
\[([^\]]*)\]|\{([^\}]*)\}
```

When using this on this text :

```
xyz[word1]abc[word2]def{word4}ghi[word5]jkl{word6}mno
```

with

```
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]*)\]|\{([^\}]*)\}/i', 'xyz[word1]abc[word2]def{word4}ghi[word5]jkl{word6}mno', $result);
```

I get an array that contains 3 arrays, with the 2 different capture groups as 2 **different** arrays.

The regex is a simple example to illustrate the question, so simplyfying the regex to use only 1 capture group is not an option. I *must* have 2 different capture groups but need them only in 1 result array.

So, is there any way to combine multiple capture groups into 1 capture-result array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|.....)` to turn multiple captures into a single one.

```
(?|\[([^\]]*)\]|\{([^\}]*)\})
```

That is, alternatives inside a branch reset group share the same capturing groups.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gN8fU7/1)